# Return a pie chart from a service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I want to create a WCF web service for generating a pie chart. For e.g I will pass two arrays to the WCF web service, and it will return a pie chart corrsponding to the passed array.

Something like this:

```
getPieChart(double[] yAxix, string[] xAxix ){
  return Chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xAxix, yAxix);
}
```

Can this be achieved? If yes please help me with code to achive this.

Comment: I would prefer putting the "chart"-generator logic in the client side (i.e. your ASP.Net application) rather than doing it in the WCF service.

Comment: Thanks for your Input Alex But I want that same chart generating login in multiple application that's the reason I thought of WCF web service

Comment: Not sure I understand that last comment. "generating login in multiple application"?

Comment: @hugh sorry for the confusion I want same chart generating **logic** in multiple application that's the reason I thought of WCF web service

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved, but only if the type you are returning from your service is [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx). In your case I am not sure as it's not certain what type you are returning.

**HOWEVER**, I agree with Alex in the comments - you should generate the chart either on the web server in the ASP.NET component, or have the client browser generate it with some kind of charting component.

Comment: return type will be an image of pie chart generated as per the input parameter

Answer (score 1):

Though not recommended, if you insist on doing this (i.e. return UI elements from a WCF service), I would probably go with sending the rendered image via WCF. Assuming you're using the chart from the `System.Web.DataVisualization` namespace you could use the [`SaveImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd488558%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method and send the result through WCF. The client can display that image.

Depending on your binding, you may want to use a technique that's suited for sending things like as images. With the HTTP bindings you may want to consider using [MTOM encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209.aspx):

> MTOM is a mechanism for transmitting large binary attachments with SOAP messages as raw bytes, allowing for smaller messages.

Your operation could look something like this:

```
public bool GetChart(object series, out byte[] chartBytes)
{
    var chart = CreateCoolChart(series);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    chart.SaveImage(ms);
    chartBytes = ms.ToArray();
    return true; // Success!
}
```

The client will have some code like this (pseudo-code):

```
object series = GetSeriesFromSomeLocation();
byte[] chartBytes;
proxy.GetChart(series, out chartBytes);
// Construct an Image object based on the chartBytes, using a stream
// Show the image in your UI control
```

Not sure if the details in the above code are entirely correct, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: yes I am using chart from System.Web.DataVisualization.Charting
can you please elaborate more on it.

Comment: I've added a little sample (pseudo) code to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeroen I will start work on it and keep updating my progress.

Comment: would like to know what object series will be and what will be the logic for function CreateCoolChart I think CreateCoolChart will contain all the logic that is inbuild in asp:chart control if yes then how can I get that logic.